# How do I set a defaut value for public double in MVC?

Tags: c#, variables, model-view-controller

In my controller I have a few variables that are type `double`. I am using one of the variables to populate a field called ExtraHours for each day of the week. Then I want to add each day to tally the week's extra hours. However, my variables return null values in which case I cannot add anything. I do not want to force an entry into the field as it is not a required field.

This is all handled in the model like below:

To Calculate the total number of extra hours for the week

```
public double? TotalExtraHours
{
    get
    {
        var E = MonExtraHours + TueExtraHours + WedExtraHours + ThuExtraHours
              + FriExtraHours + SatExtraHours + SunExtraHours;
        return E;
    }
}
```

To get the entry from the user for each day or default to 0

```
public double? MonExtraHours { get; set; } = 0.0f;
```

I have tried adding a constructor in the controller but apparently I am lost. Any guidance would be welcomed.

Comment: Your code looks okay. The only oddity if you've initialized to `0.0f` which is a `float` of value zero. It shouldn't matter, since a `float` will implicitly promote to a `double`. However, simply `0.0` would give you a `double` straight off.

Comment: Why make it nullable if you want a default value? `0` will be the default value of a non-nullable `double` property.

Comment: You do not need to assign it a float you can do 0D which is a double... Also you could not assign it a value at all and call it like this MonExtraHours.GetValueOrDefault();

Comment: Apologies, I can see the value when debugging but, it is not making it the controller on create.

Comment: The post has a value of 0 whilst the modelstate is holding a blank string, creating an invalid state.